# SQL - WHERE LIKE OR with bindParam

Tags: sql, where-clause, sql-like, bindparam

I'm trying to do an SQL search from a multiple checkbox with three options :

- Basico
- Avancado
- Interm

When the two first options are selected I suppose i'll have something like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM candidates 
WHERE catiav4 LIKE %Avançado% 
  OR catiav4 LIKE %Basico% 
ORDER BY candidate_id DESC 
LIMIT :debut,20
```

For that need I use bindParam this way

```
if ($metier13 != ''){
$metier13=implode("% OR catiav4 LIKE %",$metier13);
$metier13="%$metier13%";
$retour->bindParam(':catiav4', $metier13, PDO::PARAM_STR);}
```

It works fine when only one checkbox is selected, but when two are selected it does not return any results.

I believe I'm missing something but can't seen to find it.

Comment: I understand now my error comes from the fact that PDO adds quotes around the value. But would there be any solution to add these OR catiav4 LIKE anyway ?

Comment: it only seems logical that bindParam accepts only one value. you can try to bind param for each value in your query builder.